# Does Google Wallet / Google Wallet for digital goods API Support 3D-Secure?

Tags: android-pay, 3d-secure

I am seeing a  % of failed transactions with Google Wallet. The error message that I get is

> You cancelled this order. Reason: Other. Message sent to the customer: We were unable to process your order..

I have phoned for Wallet support and I've been told that the two examples of failed transactions were down to latency issues.

Whilst I haven't been able to prove it - I suspect that Google Wallet doesn't support 3D-Secure

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-D_Secure

A google search gives me more questions and doubt but no definitive answer

Does anyone have any experience with this working / not working?

Ben

Comment: My card is verified by Visa(3D secure) but I'm still able to purchase using it on Google Play.  I think it could be a number of things, and typically app store failure rates are not 0%.  It could range from bad credit cards, to friendly fraud, etc etc.  What's your failure percentage?

Comment: @PengYing, does google wallet simply avoid 3d-secure questions somehow?

Comment: I think Google Play is built to not handle 3DS _properly_. From the below I gather that Google Wallet doesn't support and and doesn't **not** support it either. I suspect they don't interpret the request for for 3DS verification correctly and fail the transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the below email response from Google support, hopefully it will make the situation clearer for others having similar issues.

> Please be advised that Google Wallet does not currently support 3-D Security protocol, which is used by Verified by Visa, MasterCard SecureCode and similar services. If your card-issuing bank requires this feature, we suggest using an alternate credit card for your Google Wallet transactions

Answer (score 1):

Google wallet uses direct CVV access , it is successfully carrying its operations at USA because most of the banks are using CVV tech till now, in Asia till now it is only available om discover( Dinner Club Card international Network) and JCB card issued in Japan and China. Google wallet is not supported on verified by visa or by Master-card secure code, if you want to use Google wallet you need to have a valid US address with valid US phone number, if you want the service in japan you first need to access your NFC chip present on your debit/credit card by your mobile then install Google wallet. Till now it is not present on any other Asian country , Yes it is available in Russia but you cant add more than 3000 Rebels into your Google account. Wait till it gets into your country or use similar app provided by bank/developers from your country.